# UserDAOImpl и Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, servlet, dao

Пишу проект на Servlet для связи с бд использую Hibernate. 
Кусок кода метода:

```
@Override
    public Long insertUser(User user) throws HibernateException {
        Long id;
        try{
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            id = (Long) session.save(user);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }finally{
            if(session != null && session.isOpen())
                session.close();
        }

        return id;
    }
```

Интересует вопрос, я везде пишу одно и тоже

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

session.getTransaction().commit();

if(session != null && session.isOpen())
session.close();
```

Кажется странным, что везде я пишу одно и тоже, есть ли какое-то решение для упрощения кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно например создать фильтр, в котором при поступлении запроса открывается сессия, а по окончании обработки закрывается. Все запросы на сервлет пропускаются через этот фильтр.

```
try{
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    chain.doFilter(request, response);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
} finally {
    if(session != null && session.isOpen())
        session.close();
}
```

Comment: похоже на костылёк или в продакшене так делают?

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov Нет, конечно, не делают. Здесь вообще перепутаны строки.

Comment: Так а как тогда поступить?

Comment: Почему это костылек? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#session-per-request

Comment: @carapuz rollback хде?

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov Солжный это вопрос. Если у Вас проект простой и на Hibernate 5, можете по приколу мою библиотеку поиспользовать: [fluent-hibernate](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate). Ее вот здесь используют: [RPGMaker-Tools](https://github.com/GRM-dev/RPGMaker-Tools/tree/master/rpg_mvxm/src/main/java/pl/grmdev/rpgmaker/multi/server).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вынести часто повторяющиеся строки в отдельный метод / класс. И использовать уже метод/метод класса для одного и того же.

Comment: Экономия будет незначительной, я слышал про EnityManager, но как я понимаю, его не получится использовать без spring?

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov `EnityManager`  к решению вашей задачи не иммеет отношения, так же он не имеет отношения к Spring. Это просто аналог `Session` в JPA.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.